# ERROR datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain Hadoop Configuration

Tags: windows, hadoop

I'm trying con config hadoop on Windows
I have this error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.StorageLocationChecker.check(StorageLocationChecker.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2841)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2754)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2798)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2942)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2966)
2021-10-12 11:07:43,633 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
2021-10-12 11:07:43,641 INFO datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

I already tried to set:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.failed.volumes.tolerated</name>
    <value>0</value>
  </property>
```

But, I throws other error, not working.

Comment: The issue is that the storage is failing to load for some reason. Is there an earlier error in the DN log that gives some clues about why it is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this only setting this in hadoop-env.sh :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar
```